# Youtube SDK crashing when loading live videos

Tags: android, sdk, youtube

I'm using the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment from the current sdk (v.1.0.0) to integrate YouTube videos. Usually videos play just fine, but on some devices YouTube crashes when playing live videos (and only live videos). My App doesn't crash or ANR, but nothing happens and I get a little popup to report the YouTube crash.
I added some listeners to the YouTubePlayer and it happens after onLoad().
If i don't cue or load the video, nothing happens.

Here's the LogCat output:

```
09-19 19:44:25.949  10217-10217/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: In application's main thread
    at m.b(PG:146)
    at dxk.a(PG:77)
    at dxn.a(PG:45)
    at dnf.a(PG:48)
    at dnh.a(PG:233)
    at dfm.onResponse(PG:71)
    at dnt.a(PG:48)
    at lo.run(PG:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

tested on: ASUS MeMOPad HD ME173X

any help is appreciated.

P.S.
I found this bug report:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6644

Comment: Complete same problem here. Hope Google will fix this quickly.

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai I discovered another big issue. I used the sample project and on some devices playback would stop due to a "unauthorized overlay". But, it's the sample project and I didn't overlay any views. I saw in your profile, that you are from Taiwan, if you have a chance to test it on a "Xiaomi Redmi" or other Xiaomi devices, that would be greatly appreciated. I assume it has to do with the Xiaomi launcher/framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was related to the official Youtube app version 5.10.1.5 (version code 51001051). Update 5.10.3.5 fixed this issue.
I'm using this snippet to check if an update is needed and get a localised prompt if necessary:

```
private static final int REQ_CODE_UPDATE_YOUTUBE = 1;
...
if (YouTubeIntents.getInstalledYouTubeVersionCode(getActivity()) == 51001051) {
    // this specific youtube version crashed when cueing live videos
    // versions above and below should be fine
    YouTubeInitializationResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED.getErrorDialog(getActivity(),
            REQ_CODE_UPDATE_YOUTUBE).show();
}
```